# How to change height of Region in APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, regions

I'm trying to change the height of a Region however the height which i enter seems to add height to the region.

To test, i changed the width of the Region which successfully increased the width of the Region. So i dont understand why 'height' doesnt seem to work.

As you can see from the screen print, the region increases in width but if i increase the height, it adds it below the region's border (which is the aqua color).

This is entered into Region Attributes row in its properties:

```
STYLE="height:1000px; width:1000px; background-color:aqua;"
```

Am i going wrong somewhere when trying to change the height?

[image]

Comment: Possibly you are not changing the height of the correct page element. I suggest you use Firefox and the Firebug plugin. This lets you see exactly what element you are viewing and its properties.

Comment: What Rene said is good advice: inspect your DOM and check the already applied styles to your element. But also important is the theme you are using and which page and region template you have selected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with Apex 4.2.5.00.08 and this is how I resolved this issue.

Background:
I was working on a 'single page' view of the information in my application, using different panes to list various collections of information.
Each pane was a Classic Report (with hyperlinks to the individual details) as you cannot have more than one Interactive Report on a page.

My problem was that some collections had more data than others, resulting in my panes being different sizes. I was able to control the width of the panes by setting each Region Attributes to `style="width:410px;"` (based on my screen resolution less a few pixels divided by the number of regions across the page - in this case 3).

The height was a different matter. The pane height was always adjusted to match the quantity of information in each collection.

Solution:
In the Header and Footer - Region Header I placed the following:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; min-height: 250px; max-height: 250px;">
```

and in the Region Footer I placed:

```
</div>
```

I suppose you could have different values for `min-height` and `max-height` so that a pane/region could adjust within a range. My objective was to ensure they were consistently the same size.

What happens when the information in the collection is greater than the displayable pane size is that a scroll bar is displayed on the right hand side of the pane, making it possible for users to scroll down that collective list.

What that means for layout is that your panes remain a fixed size. Where there is a lack of information in the collection, there is some blank space within the region. When you allow Apex to do the sizing for you, there is still the blank space as per the form's background.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in your region header

`<div style="overflow: auto; min-height: 250px; max-height: 250px;">`